# Need to redeclare overridden functions in descendant .h file

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a base class B, and in b.h I declare virtual function vf(), and regular function f().

I have a descendant class D, in which I wish to override vf().  I have implemented vf() in d.cpp

1. Do I have to declare vf() in d.h ?   (With the exact same signature)
2. If I do NOT override function f(), do I also have to redeclare f() in d.h ?

Comment: The short answer: yes.

Comment: Could you explain why?  Since vf is declared in B, why should a descendant have to create a prototype for everything it wants to override?  (Also I've expanded my question)

Comment: Are you looking for a deeper answer than "because the standard say so"?

Comment: I ask why because I get strange compiler results.  I figure I must be missing some concept.  (i.e. if already declared, why redeclare the exact same thing)?  But I suppose if "because the standard says so" is the reason then ok

Comment: Then post "compiler results" and the code causing them here. Also you can not override `f()` at all since it is not virtual. You can only introduce new function with the same name that will hide olde one.

Comment: Redeclaring the base type's member function in a derived class is how you communicate that the derived class is overloading that function. By not redeclaring it, you communicate that the derived class should just use the base type's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member function declarations and definitions go hand in hand. You cannot define a member function unless it is declared. If you declare member function and do not define it, you are likely going to see undefined function error at link time. The `virtual` aspect of a function declaration is orthogonal.

Coming to your questions,

> 1. Do I have to declare vf() in d.h ? (With the exact same signature)

Yes.

> 2. If I do NOT override function f(), do I also have to redeclare f() in d.h ?

No.

Comment: Definition without declaration? If I define the function inline within the class, I have no (explicit, at least) declaration any more...

Comment: @Aconcagua, an inline definition is a declaration too.

Comment: Would it not make sense for the compiler to use the declaration for the function overridden in d.cpp, with the declaration in b.h ?  Is there common sense reason I'm missing - why redeclare if it's already declared in the base class?  (Sorry if this seems obtuse - I just need a clear reason so I don't keep making the same mistake)

Comment: @TSG From compiler view, that would easily be possible. Standard commitee probably did decide differently to make it really obvious (for the user of your derived class `D`) that such a thing is ongoing. Similar reasoning probably: if you overload (not override) the function from `B` within `D` and still want to have the inherited function available, you need to include (in d.h, within the class): `using B::vf;`... Same intention again the new (C++11) override keyword..

Comment: @TSG, I suspect construction of the virtual table will be a problem if the `virtual` function is defined without being declared.